# Add new column to data frames in list

Tags: r, list, lapply

I have a set of data frames named df_1968, df_1969, df_1970, ..., df_2016 collected in a list called my_list. 
I want to add a new column in each of these data frames which simply is the current year (1968 in df_1968 and so on). I've managed to do it by looping through the data frames but I am looking for a more neat solution. I've tried the following:

```
# Function to extract year from name of data frames
substrRight <- function(y,  n) {
substr(y, nchar(y) - n  + 1, nchar(y))
}

# Add variable "year" equal to 1968 in df_1968 and so on
my_list <- lapply(my_list, function(x) cbind(x, year <- as.numeric(substrRight(names(x), 4 ))))
```

However this throws the error:

```
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) :
  arguments imply differing numbers of rows: 18878, 7
```

I can see that the way I assign the value to the variable probably does not make sense but can't wrap my head around how to do it instead. Help appreciated.

Note that the substrRight function seems to be working perfectly fine and that

```
as.numeric(substrRight(names(x), 4 ))
```

yields the vector of years 1968-2016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works in Base-R

```
years <- sub(".*([0-9]{4}$)","\\1",names(my_list))
new_list <- lapply(1:length(years), function(x) cbind(my_list[[x]],year=years[x]))
names(new_list) <- names(my_list)
```

with this self-made example data

```
df_1968 = data.frame(a=c(1,2,3),b=c(4,5,6))
df_1969 = data.frame(a=c(1,2,3),b=c(4,5,6))
df_1970 = data.frame(a=c(1,2,3),b=c(4,5,6))

my_list <- list(df_1968,df_1969,df_1970)
names(my_list) <- c("df_1968","df_1969","df_1970")
```

I get this output

```
> new_list
$df_1968
  a b year
1 1 4 1968
2 2 5 1968
3 3 6 1968

$df_1969
  a b year
1 1 4 1969
2 2 5 1969
3 3 6 1969

$df_1970
  a b year
1 1 4 1970
2 2 5 1970
3 3 6 1970
```

Answer (score 0):

The following function will loop through a named list of data frames and create a column `year` with the 4 last characters of the list's names.
I have simplified the function `substrRight`a bit. Since it's the last characters that are needed, it uses `substring`, with no need for a last character position.

```
substrRight <- function(y,  n) {
  substring(y, nchar(y) - n  + 1)
}

my_list <- lapply(names(my_list), function(x){
  my_list[[x]][["year"]] <- as.numeric(substrRight(x, 4))
  my_list[[x]]
})
```

## Data creation code.

```
my_list <- lapply(1968:1970, function(i) data.frame(a = 1:5, b = letters[1:5]))
names(my_list) <- paste("df", 1968:1970, sep = "_")
```